# Dynamicaly increase date by next date schedule in mysql database date field in a for loop using php

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need help on how to increase loan repayment schedule date dynamically in the database using php mysql insert query?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $dblink = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "smcs");
    $amt=$_POST['amt'];
    $no_inst=$_POST['no_inst'];
    $grntor=$_POST[''];
    $prfdate=$_POST['prfdate'];  
    $principal = $amt/$no_inst;

    $nextsdate=date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));

    for($i=1; $i<=$no_inst; $i++){
        if($i==1){
            $schedule="INSERT INTO loan_schedule
                                (loan_code,principal,repay_date,ls_code) 
                        VALUES ('','$principal',' $prfdate','11')";

            $schedule_run=mysqli_query($dblink,$schedule);
            continue;
        }
        $schedule="INSERT INTO loan_schedule
                                (loan_code,principal,repay_date,ls_code) 
                    VALUES ('','$principal','$nextsdate','')";
        $schedule_run=mysqli_query($dblink,$schedule);

        if(!$schedule_run){
            echo "QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($dblink);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

That's my code above, what I want is if the prefered date of first installment is 2018-02-21 then the next schedule should add one month dynamically to the date in the database.

Comment: Where do you set `$date` before using it in a `date_add()` If in doubt you [can always read the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: And surely you want to increment the date inside the loop otherwise you will only set it ONCE

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry the $date is $prfdate, I have change it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Use date_add in mysql not in php 
For e.g

SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-06-15", INTERVAL 1 MONTH);